# Broken XML file after sending it via socket from java to c++

Tags: java, c++, file, sockets, client

I need some help. 
I have server socket side wrote in java and client socket side in C++.
I'm trying to send prepared XML file from server to client, seems it works but after all received file is broken at client side (only nulls in this file).
Where is the problem?

Server side sending code:

```
    public void SendBytes() throws IOException {

        File myFile = new File(XML.prepareFile());

        int fileSize = (int) myFile.length();
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[fileSize];

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

        try {
            output.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
            output.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("sendBytes(); output error");
        }

        fis.close();
        bis.close();
        output.close();
}
```

and the Client C++ side receiving method code:

```
    int Client::RecvBytes2() {
    char buffer[4096];
    int iNumBytes = 0;

    iNumBytes = recv(m_iSock, buffer, 4096, 0);

    char tmp[iNumBytes];
    for (int i = 0; i < iNumBytes; i++) {
        tmp[i] = buffer[i];
    }

    std::ofstream fout("receivedFile.xml", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    fout.write(tmp, iNumBytes);

    return iNumBytes;
}
```

Comment: You never put anything in `mybytearray`.

Comment: omg... u save my day. Everything is works after adding this 1 missing line bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

Comment: Although I understand the immediate problem is solved. Calling recv a single time and expecting to get the whole message can fail randomly due to TCP fragmentation. ( See http://www.drdobbs.com/tcp-programming-gotchas/184416578?pgno=1)